# Border radius on android overlay button

Tags: java, android

Below is the java code i am using to show overlay button in android. It shows simple box shaped. I want to add border radius on top left and top right. I search a lot but didn't find way on google. Please tell me how can i add radius.

```
wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        overlayedButton = new Button(this);
        overlayedButton.setText("text here");
        overlayedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        overlayedButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 400;
        params.width = 920;
        params.height = 550;
        wm.addView(overlayedButton, params);

        topLeftView = new View(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams topLeftParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        topLeftParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
        topLeftParams.x = 0;
        topLeftParams.y = 0;
        topLeftParams.width = 0;
        topLeftParams.height = 0;
        wm.addView(topLeftView, topLeftParams);
```

Comment: You can use a nine patch image as the background of overlayButton.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You